# How can I prevent firefox from creating windows out of tabs?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

There seems to be a "feature" to drag a tab into a window which occurs whenever a tab is dragged "down" - I end up doing this unintentionally quite often (especially on a touchpad/laptop setup) - is there any way to turn off this feature (or make the drag distance much larger?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn it off, you'll have to install the following add-on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/bug489729-disable-detach-and-t/